# Exchange sensitive information through public chat

Tags: cryptography, email, anonymity, account-security, phone

Is there a way to exchange phone numbers/email addresses through public chats with a person without giving them or other communication information away to all the other people in the public chat?

Example for a public chat can be the comments to this post right here.

Comment: Some chat systems have support for the OTR (Off-The-Record messaging) protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an asymmetric encryption.

- Create a public/private key pair.
- Share the public key in chat
- Now someone can send data to chat encrypted with your public key.
- Data can only be decrypted with your private key no body but you can read it.